# The limit $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\int_0^hf(s) \, ds$

Tags: calculus, limits, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, riemann-sum

We know that if a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous then we have

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\int_0^hf(s) \, ds=f(0).$$

What can we say if $f$ is continuous almost everywhere or satisfy some weaker condition?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of completeness: if $f$ is locally Lebesgue integrable, then for almost every point $x$ in its domain we have 
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h}f(s)\,ds=f(x) \tag1$$
This is a consequence of the [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem), which actually has a stronger assertion:
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h}|f(s)-f(x)|\,ds=0 \tag2$$